# Azure Data Factory (ADF V2) purge or delete old / unwanted pipeline activity runs

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data Factory V2 with a tumbling trigger - works great. However, in exploring cadence options in our dev environment a tumbling window was set up with a 15 second interval. This racked up a good few thousand entries in the pipeline runs activity history. I cant seem to find a way to purge or delete these failed runs - how can I clean up the history? Ideally, when I delete a trigger it would be helpful to have an option to remove all the history associated with that trigger. Is there any way of accomplishing this or similar?

[image]